# Visa requirements for Vietnam when flying with AirAsia

Tags: visas, vietnam, sgn

I am flying the 6th of July (19:40) from Kuala Lumpur to Ho Chi Minh with AirAsia. My next flight back home is the 7th of July (08:50) with Vietnam Airlines to Bangkok and then KLM to Amsterdam. I have heard people had problems with boarding without a visa.

Can I fly to Ho Chi Minh without a visa but with proof of my ticket for my next flight?

Comment: What's your citizenship ?

Comment: ...also, are both flights booked onto the same ticket?

Answer (score 1):

In case you just wait at Tan Son Nhat airport (Ho Chi Minh City) in a short time, and you do not go out of the transit area, Vietnam visa application is not necessary.

However, if your waiting time at the airport takes for several hours and you want to go out of the transit area for some reason, like to visit somewhere or meet someone in Vietnam, you should apply for a Vietnam visa.

Apply for Vietnam visa online is a common method, after the processing time, you will get a Vietnam visa approval letter. Print this letter out and with your passport, you will have the Vietnam visa stamped on the passport when you arrival Ho Chi Minh.

Thus, you will be free to enjoy your short stay in Vietnam while awaiting for the next flight.

Comment: If you will fly at the 6th of July (19:40). You should apply for a Rush Vietnam visa right now and they will process next Monday morning

Comment: My experience of flying to Vietnam (this year) was that they checked for elgibility to enter the country on boarding the plane, and would not let you board without this. Is this check waived if you have an onward ticket?

Answer (score 0):

This question is critical....as a lot people buy cheap tickets that could have a huge sting in the tail.

Air Asia is a point to point carrier. They have no airside check-in at any Vietnamese airport. If you are transiting from outside Vietnam via an airport here on Air Asia you must check-in. to check in you must clear immigration. To clear immigration you must have a VN visa. Without it you will denied boarding in your departure country by Air Asia, or deported on arrival not being allowed to enter the country to check-in again. The exception would be if you are holding a passport from a country that has a visa exemption for Vietnam.